# C# - How to you initialise a MultiSelectList as empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

does anyone know how to initialise a MultiSelectList as empty?

I have a ListBoxFor control (MVC3) which i wish the user to populate by using other text and button controls on the web page.

It doesn't like me commenting out the line below....

many thanks in advance

```
Items = new MultiSelectList(
    new[] 
    {
        //new { Id = 1, Name = "item 1" }                        
    },
    "Id",
    "Name",
    selectedItemIds
)
```

Comment: "It doesn't like me commenting out the line below..." - What doesn't it like about it?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Error 1 No best type found for implicitly-typed array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a MultiSelectList like that, one of the things the compiler checks is if there are indeed `Id` and `Name` fields in the list (IEnumerable) you provided.
The problem with your code is that there are no elements named `Id` and `Name` when you send an empty array of anonymous objects, therefore the compiler cannot conclude that this is valid code.

If you want to be able to send an empty array, you will have to refrain from using anonymous types.

Try this:

```
    public struct myListType
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
    }
```

Now you can create your MultiSelectList as follows:

```
Items = new MultiSelectList(
    new List<myListType>(),
    "Id",
    "Name"
);
```

I left out the selecteditemIDs because there is no use for it when the list is empty, it can only create issues.

Although I am still not certain why you want to do this. I suspect there is a better way, if you can elaborate your intentions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Even if this isn't what will work for me down the line then at least i have learnt something :) This is what i'm trying to do in the long run but nobody seems to know the solution so i'm breaking down the problem into smaller chunks (spent way too much time trying to figure it out as it is) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138875/how-do-you-send-html-listboxfor-data-from-a-view-to-a-model-using-c-net-with

Comment: Thanks. I think you're using the concept of a ListBox wrongly, but I'll need to check it further. I'll check your question and see if I can ppropose a solution.

Comment: ohh ok thanks! if you know another control i could use instead for my intended purposes please let me know! :)

Comment: Well a SelectList/Listbox is intended to be used if the user must choose from a closed set of options, which isn't the case here. Very basically, I would create a sumple <ul> to display this (layout can be done at a later time), then have an Ajax call create the new entries in the database, then refresh the <ul> with the current database content. I'll get into it more in your question when I find the time.

Comment: Where in God's name is this documented? And how is selectedItemIDs used?

Comment: If you use an anonymous object, the compiler is still able to verify whether a certain field is present in that anonymous object. However, if you pass an *empty* list, the compiler can't confirm nor deny, because it knows nothing about your anonymous object, and you didn't provide a list of existing objects. So the solution is either by making your objects non-anonymous (i.e. creating an actual class for it), or making sure you always provide a list of objects, never an empty one. Either solution works. I skipped the usage of the `selectedItemIDs`, since it's irrelevant for **empty** lists...

Comment: To add: the usage of selectedIDs by OP is correct, it just seems irrelevant if the specified scenario is about an empty list.